# How to display an infinite ratio to best communicate that the set contains exclusively one type?

Tags: math

I have a reporting dashboard displaying a ratio of apples to oranges normalized to 1:x such as 10 apples and 20 oranges is "1:2".

**How would I best display 0 apples 20 oranges?**

- "1:Infinity" is an option but looks weird
- "0:20" or "0:1" shouldn't be options due to the requirement of normalizing it in the form of "1:x", but really the intent is to communicate to the user that for this cell of the table there are "only oranges"

Comment: Are you also showing the actual values?

Comment: Why do actual values need to be shown?

Comment: No, I'm just showing the ratio

Answer (score 1):

You can use icons when there is no single value and not display it:

[image]

Comment: That's a cool idea, but in my particular use case, the items are abstract